# Duplicate Sounds

Tags: synthesizer, audio

I connected my Casio keyboard to an interface (vault ai22) (1/4" cables) and I also use stero headphones connected to the audio interface.i also connected the Casio USB out put to my laptop. Now I am hearing both keyboard sound (from Casio keyboard speakers) as well as from the headphones which I connected to the interface. How to not to hear the casio's speaker sound? Earlier it was working fine. But I don't know all of a sudden I am hearing sounds from both the speakers as well as the headphones. Please help me out hear.

Comment: Is anything plugged in the headphone socket on the Casio? That's the usual speaker switch.